# What do the visions seen by Flash when he got shot mean?

Tags: dc, the-flash, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

In the **Justice League Animated** TV show episode 14 *"The Brave and the Bold" - part 1* showed that Flash was shot by Dr. Corwin’s energy gun, which showed him visions starting with him turning into a lightning bolt and going back to the night where he was working in the lab and the lightning that struck him. [image]

The vision continued which showed him speed across to Central city where he turned fat and looked himself in the mirror which showed him in different odd shapes and also like a puppet on strings. At the end, He turned into a gorilla and only then he woke up from the dream/vision.

What could all these visions represent ?

Comment: It's not just his Great Ape form, is it?

Comment: @Ellesedil I don't think so

Comment: It's over nine thousand!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first vision shows what happened to Barry Allen. In the comics, Barry literally becomes the lightning bolt that strikes him in his lab, giving him his powers (this version of the Flash is Wally West, not Barry Allen). The next images are specific references to comic book events where The Flash was (apparently) turned into a puppet, and made fat. The third vision is a vision of his future where Grodd manages to turn the Justice League into apes.

[image: Flash turned into a puppet]

[image: Flash turned fat]

[image: Flash as part of JL:Ape]

The Silver Age was a very weird place, and transformations were common. So yes, these are likely visions of what happened in the comic books (i.e. basically alternate realities that the cartoon Flash could have interacted with).

Comment: You answered this much better than I did.

Comment: Not in the least. :) I've never seen the episode in question, so I was guessing. Feel free to move over any or all of those images to your answer.

Comment: @Robert  
If this can be put in one answer, I could close the question :)

Comment: I'll add my explanation to Sean's answer and delete my answer.

Answer (score -1):

It also works metaphorically because I think that scene was Flash's perspective of being mind controlled by Grodd. The Fat part was specifically a scheme of Grodd's when he was in a human body.