Can you identify a cartoon in which Flash became fat?
I have this animated show/ movie scene in my mind: Flash is running and suddenly he becomes fat. Then, he goes out of breath.
It may also have Mirror Master because Flash also saw his distorted images in three mirrors (possibly, images made him fat).

This is Justice League (2001) Episode 14: The Brave and the Bold, Part I.

Flash experience a series of bizarre hallucinations before waking up to find himself in a jail cell.




The episode mirrors the comic serial, The Flash #115




Non-dupe, but this episode was asked about at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72682/what-do-the-visions-seen-by-flash-when-he-got-shot-mean, including some of the other visions and their comic book ties.

I'm pretty sure there was a blink and you'll miss it hat-tip to that legendary Flash issue on the TV show as well.
